# Python double FOR loops without threading

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, grid, multitasking

Basically, I want to make a grid with school subjects and all the test results I got from it, and I want to display about 10 results for every subject.

Like this:

```
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
English| 7.4 | 6.4 | 9.5 | 4.5 | 8.9 | 3.9 | 8.0 | 6.5 | 9.9 | 4.9 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Dutch  | Results
...
```

And I made basically two FOR loops, one reading every school subject out of a list and one that reads every result out of a list.
However, I want them to complete without going "stuck" in the next loop.
How do I do this? Do I thread the two loops and make a time delay so the values are readable every x seconds? (Probably not this, this is very slow)

Code:

```
...
for item in store: #Loop that reads the subjects
        with open("matrixcontent.dat", "r") as matrixcontent_open:
            lines = matrixcontent_open.readlines() #Lines are test results
        for line in lines:
            print(item + "|" + line + "\n" + ("-------------" * 7))
            #I want this last line to print the subject and than all the results
```

EDIT:

### With the solution (somewhat) down below, it will print all the test results, but It will print it wrong. How do I manage to print all the test results in one individual column/row? I would like all these number to be in the NTL (Dutch) row.

NTL  |  7.2

---

ETL  |  8.4

---

WIB  |  6.7

---

WID  |  5.3

---

ICT  |  4.8

---

NAS  |  9.4

---

### SCK  |  10.0

Comment: What do you mean by "going stuck"?

Comment: @kindall It will start in the store loop, than continue in the lines loop and stay there untill its done. I want it to complete after each other, but not after the first one is done.

Comment: so `matrixcontent.dat` has data for all your items?  is new content added to the end?

Comment: @cmd matrixcontent.dat contains all the test results, and no new content gets added.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your `matrixcontent.dat` contains all the scores for each subject, one set per line, and the order of the lines correspond to the order of the subjects in your `store` list variable.

In which case, you only need one loop, either over the lines in `matrixcontent.dat` or over the `store` variable.

Something like this ought to work...

```
with open("matrixcontent.dat", "r") as matrixcontent_open:
    for item in store:
        line = next(matrixcontent_open)
        print(item + "|" + line + "\n" + ("-------------" * 7))
```

Comment: This sounds logical, but I get a `line = next(matrixcontent_open)
StopIteration` error.

Comment: @IPDGino Looks like I assumed incorrectly. It would help to specify the format of your `matrixcontent.dat` file in the OP.

Comment: I figured it out -> [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283144/python-for-loop-in-a-list-in-a-print-function