# Python FOR Loop in a list in a print function

Tags: python, list, for-loop, printing

I have another question about somewhat the same problem as I had here ->
[Python double FOR loops without threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280529/python-double-for-loops-without-threading)

Basically, I want the first for loop down here to enumerate over every school subject in a list, and then inside the print function, I want it to print every number that is in that list, so It comes out like 8 - 4 - 5 - 7 etc.

```
    for item in store:
        print(str(item + "|" + (str((cflist[i]) for i in range(3))) + "\n" + ("-------------" * 7)))
...
Running the complete code makes a big grid filled with these things, but different
subjects each line. (NTL here)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NTL|<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000003404900>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have had the code working partially, so that each list number was in another subject line, so I would have `NTL|8.2` and the next line `ENT|5.7` But I want all those numbers to display after each other like `NTL|8.2 - 5.7 - etc`

EDIT:
Done!

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NTL|7.2 8.4 6.7 5.3 4.8
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str` on a generator expression will print `str` version of generator expression, not it's items as you expected:

```
>>> str((x for x in range(3)))
'<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb624b93c>'
```

Try something like this:

```
for item in store:
   strs = " ".join([cflist[i]) for i in range(3)])
   print(str(item + "|" + strs + "\n" + ("-------------" * 7)))
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. Now I need to make one of those for every subject line.

Comment: One more question, is there a way to make the `for i in range(3)` go in `for i in range(all items in the list)`?

Comment: @IPDGino You can also use `" ".join(cflist)`, this will join all items of the `cflist`.